# How to get the BlobKey for a statically uploaded image file

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using GAE Python and am trying to serve a default pic when the user has not uploaded any pic in his profile. 
I have a static .png file present in the /images directory which i intend to use as the default profile pic(see app.yaml entry for it below).

```
:: 
runtime: python27 
handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: images
```

Problem: I want to get the BlobKey for this file to use in "images.get_serving_url(blob_key_value)" later.

I know how to get the BlobKey for a dynamically uploaded file(see below) but i am not able to get it for a statically uploaded image file shown above.

```
upload_files = self.get_uploads('file') 
blob_info = upload_files[0]
logging.info ("blob_key is [%s] ", str(blob_info.key()))
```

Could you please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you think a static image has a blob key. Blob keys are for, not surprisingly, files that are stored in the blobstore. But a static image is uploaded alongside your program code, and is not stored in the blobstore, so does not have a blob key.

I'm not sure why you need one. When you're calculating the image URL, you can just check if you have a blob key: if so, use `get_serving_url`, otherwise use the static image path.

Comment: I wanted to store the static image file in the Blobstore so that i do not need to do a check for Blob key existence. But, i would go with your suggestion of checking the existence of Blob key to decide the value of the URL to be used for the pic. 
Thanks for your time and suggestion..